# How can I prevent a responsive div from going into another div using CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I have some fixed pixel divs on the top and bottom and a responsive one in the middle.  How can I prevent it from going into the top div when the screen is adjusted small?

Here is a working example to illustrate the problem.  I want to be able to make the browser small and not have the black box go into the red.  While maintaining the responsiveness.

```
<div style="position:relative; height:100px; width:100%; background:red;"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RHZLr

Comment: you did have to learn what it really means to be responsive, and fix the way you have everything coded atm.

Comment: I need the width to be 100% and not fixed as I have bootstrap stuff that needs to remain responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using width:100% try using a fixed width. Fixed widths don't move so you won't have to worry about them invading other divs.

#### Also!

It might behoove you to use CSS media queries to give the divs a fixed (non moving) position once the screen gets to a certain size.

e.x.

```
#div1{
  position:relative; 
  left:25%; 
  width:50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
   #div1{
      width:500px;
      height:500px;
   }
}
```

## [Working Pen!](http://codepen.io/austinkregel/pen/bmacK)

(codepen.io example)

Answer (score 0):

I would forget absolute positioning in this case. Make all the boxes relatively positioned, and use margins to position the black box as you please. This way responsiveness works as desired.

### Working Fiddle

```
#blackBox{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: black;
}
```